# How to hide the Menu bar only in a page

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I just want to remove the tittle bar (header) (blue side part in image)inside this page.[image: image with header bar]

my ionic code in about.html page

```
<nav-page hide-nav-bar="true">


<ion-view>
<ion-content class="app-view">
    <div class="list-inset-feed">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            <div class="row responsive-sm text-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <h1 class="text-white">{{"about_page_title" | translate}}</h1>
                    <h3 class ="text-white">version 1.0.0</h1>

                    <div class="image_container">
                    <img alt="logo" height="100"  src="img/logo.png">
                    </div>
                    <a class="text-white" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://abcd.html', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
            privacy policy
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: just try removing that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `hide-nav-bar="true"` inside your `<ion-view>` tag.

**HTML**

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
      <ion-content >
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```